# Unable to Import table from Azure Data lake Storage in Analysis Service Tabular project

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-analysis-services, analysisservices

I am trying to import three CSV file in Analysis Service Tabular Project, created in Visual Studio. The three files contain 2.5,7.2 and .2 million records. When I am trying to import these files as a table in the tabular project it is taking too long time(for one file only) and after one hour it is giving timeout error and no table imported. 
My objective is to store all the CSV files as a table and write some DAX queries and deploy this model to Azure Analysis Service so that I can connect this model to Power BI.
 Is there any better approach or solution for this? I have increased timeout time to 12 hours but still facing timeout issue.

Comment: Start with some small sample files?

Comment: Hi wBob. I have used Azure Analysis Service before with small files. This time I am using 1 GB files and facing this challenge.